# How can i open a v-dialog outside of a template?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

How can i open a dialog outside of the template?

```html
<v-dialog v-model="dialog_elimina_richiesta" activator="dialog_elimina_richiesta" persistent>
  <v-card>
    <v-card-title class="headline">Use Google's location service?</v-card-title>
    <v-card-text>Let Google help apps determine location. This means sending anonymous location data to Google, even when no apps are running.</v-card-text>
    <v-card-actions>
      <v-spacer></v-spacer>
      <v-btn color="green darken-1" text @click="dialog_elimina_richiesta = false">Disagree</v-btn>
      <v-btn color="green darken-1" text @click="dialog_elimina_richiesta = false">Agree</v-btn>
    </v-card-actions>
  </v-card>
</v-dialog>

<template v-slot:item.data_richiesta="{ item }">{{item.data_richiesta | formatDate}}</template>
<template v-slot:item.actions="{ item }">
    <v-icon medium class="mr-2" color="purple" @click="editAttivita(item)">mdi-pencil</v-icon>
    <v-icon
      medium
      class="mr-2"
      color="red"
      @click="detailDeleterichiesta(item)"
    >mdi-delete</v-icon>
      
</template>
```

and there is my function which should open the dialog, and i don't know why it doesn't work, the property `dialog_elimina_richiesta` should be accessible from everywhere using `this.property`, and with the dialog that has the `v-model` on that property i can't get why it doesn't work

```js
    detailDeleterichiesta(item){
      this.dialog_elimina_richiesta=true;
      console.log(item);          
    },
```

Comment: Can you reproduce your issue in codesandbox?

Comment: Actually no cause its a section fo code of a bigger project

Comment: Because i tried to open a dialog through a method and it is working fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please find the below code where the dialog is opened outside the template.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data() {
    return {
      dialog: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    openDialog: function() {
      this.dialog = true
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@5.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app">
    <v-app id="inspire">
      <v-row justify="center">
        <v-btn color="primary" dark @click.stop="openDialog">
          Open Dialog
        </v-btn>

        <v-dialog v-model="dialog" max-width="290">
          <v-card>
            <v-card-title class="headline">User Data?</v-card-title>

            <v-card-text>
              Data </v-card-text>

            <v-card-actions>
              <v-spacer></v-spacer>

              <v-btn color="green darken-1" text @click="dialog = false">
                Disagree
              </v-btn>

              <v-btn color="green darken-1" text @click="dialog = false">
                Agree
              </v-btn>
            </v-card-actions>
          </v-card>
        </v-dialog>
      </v-row>
    </v-app>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```